# coin flip using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to display either heads or tails when a button is clicked. I'm not sure where I'm going wrong. It seems like a pretty simple thing to do but maybe I'm missing something? Here is what I have.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Assignment 9</title> 
        <link href="images/avatar.png" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png">
        <link href="css/stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <script src="js/javascript.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <style type="text/css">
        .auto-style1 {
            text-align: center;
        }
        </style>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <header>
    </header>
    <aside>
    </aside>
    <div id="main">
    <h1> Arrays and Coditional Statements</h1>

    <h2 class="auto-style1"> Quote of the Day</h2>


    <h2 class="auto-style1">Flip a coin </h2>
    <script>
  <script>
function myFunction1{
var x =Math.floor(Math.random()*2);
if ( x==0){
document.getElementById("Coin").innerHTML= "Heads";
}
else{
document.getElementById("Coin").innerHTML= "Tails";
}}

myFunction1();



</script>
<button type="button" onclick="myFunction1" id="Coin"> CLick ME</button>


    </div>
    <footer>
    </footer>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Along with advice from @Barmar also `function myFunction1{` should be `function myFunction1(){`

Comment: In addition to below you wrote <script> twice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few things:

1. Redundant `script` tag just below the one that's actually needed
2. You need `()` on your `onclick` call - `onclick="myFunction1()"`
3. You also need `()` on your function definition: `function myFunction1() {`
4. At the time of the first call to `myFunction1()`, your `Coin` element does not yet exist - put the script *after* that element's creation, or in a `window.onload` handler.

Putting those fixes together:

```html
<button type="button" onclick="myFunction1()" id="Coin">CLick ME</button>
<script>
  function myFunction1() {
    var x = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2);
    console.log(x);
    if (x == 0) {
      document.getElementById("Coin").innerHTML = "Heads";
    } else {
      document.getElementById("Coin").innerHTML = "Tails";
    }
  }

  myFunction1();
</script>
```

The [JavaScript console](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/8525/how-to-open-the-javascript-console-in-different-browsers) would have told you about these problems, one-by-one, as you solved them. I recommend getting familiar with it.

Comment: If I wanted to display a picture of the side of a coin determining what number is generator, could I just add the image into the appropriate if or else statement?

Comment: It doesn't seem to work. I added an img tag and set its src but it doesn't show the picture when the button is clicked

Answer (score 3):

You can use this single line of JavaScript to get either `heads` or `tails`

```
console.log(Math.random() >= 0.5 ? "heads" : "tails")
```

Answer (score 1):

You forget `()` after `myFunction1`

Answer (score 1):

You're not calling the function in your `onclick` attribute, you're just naming it. Functions are called by putting `()` (to enclose the arguments) after the function name. So it should be

```
onclick="myFunction1()"
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution:

Assignment 9 
        
        
        
        
        .auto-style1 {
            text-align: center;
        }

## Arrays and Coditional Statements

```
<h2 class="auto-style1"> Quote of the Day</h2>


<h2 class="auto-style1">Flip a coin </h2>
```

CLick ME

```
myFunction1();

function myFunction1() {
var x =Math.floor(Math.random()*2);
if ( x==0){
document.getElementById("Coin").innerHTML= "Heads";
}
else{
document.getElementById("Coin").innerHTML= "Tails";
}
}
```

```
</div>
<footer>
</footer>
</body>
</html>
```